# Why do I get a ReferenceError for Knockout js when using a data-bind ='if' in a table row

Tags: knockout.js

I am a little confused. I am getting "ReferenceError: showActiveOnly is not defined" when I attempt to call "if:(showActiveOnly)" in a td tag, but immediataly under it I placed a p tag just as a test and have its data-bind set to "text:showActiveOnly", and this is read find. What am I missing?

```
var viewmodel = {
            userList:UserListViewModel(users),
            showActiveOnly : ko.observable(true)
        }
        ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);

<div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: showActiveOnly" /><p data-bind="text:$data.showActiveOnly"></p>

        <table >
            <thead>
                <tr data-bind="click: sortTable">
                    <th>
                        User Name
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: currentPage ">
                <tr data-bind="if:(showActiveOnly)">
                    <p data-bind="text:showActiveOnly"></p>
                    <td data-bind="text: Username" style="width: 10%;"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

error: uncaught error: unable to parse bindings. 
Message: ReferenceError: showActiveOnly is not defined;
binding value: if(showActiveOnly)

Comment: I dont really understand your code here. But do you really want to have a new tbody for each currentPage? You dont want a new tr for each? In that case you should have data-bind="foreach: currentPage " on the tr element instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changed answer a bit. I think problem here i scope/context. But also have a suggestion of what i think you might want to achive with this table. Here demonstrated using virtual element instead and foreach on tr element instead of tbody.

Example of what i think you want. That is if each currentPage has an showActiveOnly observable. If showActiveOnly is not present on each currentPage you can use $parent, $parents[index] or $root to get the right scope for that observable. As described here https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: currentPage ">
        <!-- ko if: showActiveOnly -->
        <p data-bind="text:showActiveOnly"></p>
        <td data-bind="text: Username" style="width: 10%;"></td>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Downvoted because this is incorrect, you can data-bind an if onto any kind of element, the problem here must be the context

Comment: @MKougiouris Alright. Just remembered something with <li> and if bindings beeing a problem. Thought it might affect others aswell as per the documentation where they use the virtual binding instead for li elements. https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html

Comment: Not exactly. The documentation uses the <i> as an example, not because there is a problem binding on them. But in that example if they were to bind on the <ul> the would not be able to have the first <li> been static. This is why they show there as an example the containerles syntax,
`<ul>
    <li>This item always appears</li>
    <!-- ko if: someExpressionGoesHere -->
        <li>I want to make this item present/absent dynamically</li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>`

Comment: @nios thanks so much. the $root thing is what I was missing. Worked perfectly. I stumbled across the <!--ko if --> thing too, but I could not get that to work. I would upvote it, but cant because too low of rep. But seriously thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <tbody data-bind="foreach: currentPage ">
                <tr data-bind="if: $parent.showActiveOnly">
                    <p data-bind="text:showActiveOnly"></p>
                    <td data-bind="text: Username" style="width: 10%;"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

since you are using foreach you are changing the context for the contained binds.
THis is why you must use $parent or $root. Search for knockout data contexts info at knockoutJS site, it contains every little detail!